# Integrating view-flow with google-drive django api

Tags: python, django, django-viewflow

My company is setting up a workflow aplication and they've chosen the viewflow library for designing it. I have little experience with django and have to integrate it with google drive but I wouldnt know hoy to modify the standard front end that comes with viewflow without starting it from scratch. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewflow is the thin workflow layer on top of django. Viewflow frontend is just a set of predefined views and templates. Viewflow frontend customization has no difference than any other django apps customization.

So for the django and google drive integration, there is [django-googledrive](https://django-googledrive-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package that looks promising.